# PostgreSQL inherited foreign key workaround/issue?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, foreign-keys

I have a number of tables in Postgres that are also nodes in a graph I maintain with a transitive reflexive closure table. I had wanted to make the different tables inherit from a shared "node" table. Unfortunately there is a known issue regarding foreign key constraints on a parent table:

> Specifying that another table's column REFERENCES cities(name) would allow the other table to contain city names, but not capital names. There is no good workaround for this case.
>   -([PostgreSQL Documentation : Inheritance : Caveats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS))

Which means that my relationship table cannot have a constraint on nodes because the id's technically belong to the child tables.

Has anyone found a clever work-around that isn't in the documentation?
Given that "These deficiencies will probably be fixed in some future release", is there a open issue that I can follow?

Comment: I'm not aware of any clever workarounds. You can emulate it with user-defined triggers, but there are some hairy concurrency issues that way. There's no open bug or issue to follow  as PostgreSQL is extremely old-school and refuses to use an issue tracker (argh!), you'd just want to keep an eye on the pgsql-hackers mailing list. I am not aware of any current work on inherited tables and unique indexes.